# Is the Axiom of choice intuitive? How was it first introduced?

Tags: intuition, axiom-of-choice, axioms

I will refer to the Axiom of choice as ($AC$).
As far as I know, the widely accepted axioms of set theory is the Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms together with the $AC$. But the last axiom seems to be the most special out of these axioms.

I have read that the $AC$ is the most controversial axiom in the entire history of mathematics. Yet it remains a crucial assumption not only in set theory but equally in modern algebra, analysis, mathematical logic, and topology (I think when we use the Zorn´s lemma, we also use the properties of the $AC$?).

How I understand the $AC$ intuitively is that it is ​needed when you need to make infinitely many arbitrary choices at once.

**My question is**: For many other axioms, we really can tell "yes, this property makes sense to demand." We know from the real world. But is this the case of $AC$?

If not, probably somebody in the history decided it is important and that we need to demand $AC$. That´s why I want to ask:

What is the origin of the axiom of choice, why was it introduced?

What are areas of math where it helps? Was there any particular problem that needed the $AC$ to be solved? And only after that it was discovered to be useful also in other areas?

Thank you for response and if needed, I can try to make any part of the question more specific.

Comment: Not so intuitive... The ["evidence" of AC](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/#OriChrAxiCho) was a long process.

Comment: Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to AC. Most modern algebraists assume AC, they need the existence of maximal ideals everywhere and this is equivalent to AC.

Comment: "That a product of nonempty sets is nonempty is obvious; clearly, it is absurd that every set can be well-ordered; and as for Zorn's Lemma—who knows?"

Comment: In the real world, if you have a bunch of bags, none of which is empty, do you think you can pick one object out of each one? Does it make intuitive sense?

Comment: I think it's controversial because it's simultaneously powerful but carries some (arguably big) assumptions. We, as mathematicians, like to minimize assumptions (axioms) whilst maximizing their creative potential. AC performs really well on potential, perhaps too well, as some might say...

Comment: Also, when phrased in different ways it becomes more or less intuitive to different people. For example, when phrased as the well-ordering theorem, it may seem too magical to well-order everything. But when phrased as a "selection from bags", it becomes nearly obvious.

Comment: By the way, it's not usual to give "of" its own capital letter in an initialism, e.g., we write FBI not FBOI. You can save yourself some typing and perhaps be better understood if you use the customary abbreviation AC as you see in the comments.

Comment: Yes AC is used to abbreviate *axiom of choice* not AOC